# Getting an error trying to run rapidapi call using async and await

Tags: javascript, async-await, rapidapi

I keep getting the following error when I try to run a `GET` request from Rapid API

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Cannot access 'getData' before initialization
```

```js
const RAPIDAPI_KEY =
  import.meta.env.VITE_RAPIDAPI_KEY;
const GEOLOCATION_URL = "https://ip-geo-location.p.rapidapi.com/ip/check?format=json";
const GEOLOCATION_HOST = "ip-geo-location.p.rapidapi.com";

const getData = async(url, host) => {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      accept: "application/json",
      "x-rapidapi-host": host,
      "x-rapidapi-key": RAPIDAPI_KEY
    }
  })

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`)
  }

  return await response.json();
}

const runApiQueries = async() => {
  // GET CITY NAME
  const getData = await getData(GEOLOCATION_URL, GEOLOCATION_HOST);
  console.log(getData);
}

runApiQueries();
```

Comment: Try changing the variable name in runApiQueries method, maybe due to the same name, javascript compiler getting confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the line

```
  const getData = await getData(GEOLOCATION_URL, GEOLOCATION_HOST);
```

it should've been

```
  const data = await getData(GEOLOCATION_URL, GEOLOCATION_HOST);
```

Under any circumstances, you shouldn't specify variable name the same as function or any other defined identifier.